# Ugly-nice double series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to evaluate the following ugly double sum (presented in raw notation as used in my calculations):
$\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{4 m \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  m x}{T_x}\right) \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  n y}{T_y}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  m l_x}{T_x}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n l_y}{T_y}\right) \left(1-\exp \left(-\pi  h \sqrt{\left(\frac{m}{T_x}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{n}{T_y}\right){}^2}\right) \cosh \left(2 \pi  z \sqrt{\left(\frac{m}{T_x}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{n}{T_y}\right){}^2}\right)\right)}{\pi ^2 \left(n T_x^2 \left(\left(\frac{m}{T_x}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{n}{T_y}\right){}^2\right)\right)}$

At the first step, the term **without** the exponentials $\exp \left(-\pi  h \sqrt{\left(\frac{m}{T_x}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{n}{T_y}\right){}^2}\right) \cosh \left(2 \pi  z \sqrt{\left(\frac{m}{T_x}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{n}{T_y}\right){}^2}\right)$ is not so difficult to evaluate by using residue calculus. In this case h>2z so Jordan's lemma is valid.

The major difficulties arise when dealing with the square roots at the exponent. We have a branch cuts that make things more difficult. At this point I failed to find a nice contour of integration.

Although the sum looks quite symmetric, I wasn't able to separate the variables and transform the double sum to a product of sums.

I assume, finding the following sum as a function of n
$\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } \frac{m \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  m x}{T_x}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  m l_x}{T_x}\right) \exp \left(-\pi  (h-2 z) \sqrt{\left(\frac{m}{T_x}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{n}{T_y}\right){}^2}\right)}{n \left(\left(\frac{m}{T_x}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{n}{T_y}\right){}^2\right)}$ will be instrumental in calculating the whole sum.

If following the approach with contour integration, the following integral will be of interest: $\oint \text{d$\xi $}\left(\frac{\xi  \cos (2 \pi  \xi  x) \sin \left(\pi  \xi  l_x\right) \cot \left(\pi  \xi  T_x\right) \exp \left(-\pi  (h-2 z) \sqrt{\xi ^2+\left(\frac{n}{T_y}\right){}^2}\right)}{n \left(\xi ^2+\left(\frac{n}{T_y}\right){}^2\right)}\right)$

I would appreciate any advise on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Did you lose a bet or something?

Comment: @Pedro This sum is of practical interest. I'm calculating the demag tensor field of an infinite array of rectangular magnets. Tx, Ty, lx, ly and h are geometric parameters of the array.

Comment: I was just being funny. ;)